# How to get the Matching and Non-matching records from two input files in one step using SYNCSORT?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have a requirement like below.

-> I have 2 input files FILE1 and FILE2.

-> Write the matching records into a FILE3.

-> Write the Non matching records from FILE1 into FILE4.

-> Write the Non matching records from FILE2 into FILE5.

The key position in both the Input Files is (1,10).

Can anybody please let me know the SORTCARD, how Can I get this in single step in SyncSort??

Thanks in Advance,
Rajasekhar Jannu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(01,10,A)
JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(01,10,A)
UNPAIRED F1,F2   <== This results in cartesian product
REFORM FIELDS=(F1:01,10,F2:01,10),FILL=C'$'
SORT FIELDS=(01,10,CH,A)
OUTFIL FNAMES=03,
INCLUDE=(01,01,CH,NE,C'$',AND,11,01,CH,NE,C'$')  <== Matched Records
OUTFIL FNAMES=04,
INCLUDE=(01,01,CH,NE,C'$',AND,11,01,CH,EQ,C'$')  <== Non-Matched Records from File1
OUTFIL FNAMES=03,
INCLUDE=(01,01,CH,EQ,C'$',AND,11,01,CH,NE,C'$')  <== Non-Matched Records from File2
```

Also, note that only 10bytes have been considered from both the files as you didnt mention the lengths of each file.

Also suggest you to search known mainframe forums and post it here if you dont get the working solution. Hope this helps

Refer this:
[Joinkeys Guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.icea100/ice1ca50116.htm)

Comment: Hi Raja Anna, Can you please explain about FILL=C'$'? why we are appending the '$' sign here?

Comment: It is not being appended, rather padded. While comparing two files we are creating a reformatted intermediate record with data from each input file. The character(s) given in FILL keyword will be padded in the place of data of unmatched input file. If still you are not clear, go thru the reference given in the response

Comment: That does not produce a "Cartesian Product" (unless keys on both files are equal). As the REFORMAT record must contain data sourced from at least one record, the OUTFILs can be simplified, and OUTFIL,SAVE used for the matched records.

Answer (score 2):

```
enter code here
//JOIN EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SORTJNF1 DD * 
1234567890 FILEB 
1234678901 FILE1 
/* 
//SORTJNF2 DD * 
1234567890 FILEB 
1234789012 FILE2 
/* 
//JNF1CNTL DD DUMMY             <=== not necessary(informatory)
//JNF2CNTL DD DUMMY             <=== not necessary(informatory)
//BOTH     DD DSN=<FILENAME>
//FILE1 DD DSN=<file name> 
//FILE2 DD DSN=<file name>
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*           <=== we can see the JOIN output here(explanatory)
//SYSIN DD * 
 JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,10,A) 
 JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(1,10,A) 
 JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2 
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,16,F2:1,16),FILL=C'@' 
 OPTION COPY 
 OUTFIL FNAMES=BOTH, 
 INCLUDE=(01,01,CH,NE,C'@',AND,17,01,CH,NE,C'@'),BUILD=(1,16)
 OUTFIL FNAMES=FILE1,
 INCLUDE=(01,01,CH,NE,C'@',AND,17,01,CH,EQ,C'@'),BUILD=(1,16)
 OUTFIL FNAMES=FILE2,
 INCLUDE=(01,01,CH,EQ,C'@',AND,17,01,CH,NE,C'@'),BUILD=(17,16)
 /*  

 //***** this REFORMAT output would be something like
 1234567890 FILEB1234567890 FILEB 
 1234678901 FILE1@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@1234789012 FILE2  
 //*********************************
```

FILL=C'@' pads the charecter '@' to the record produced by JOIN operation, so that this padded charecter can be used later at the time of Filter using INCLUDE

Comment: How did you manage to get two upvotes? You never need to dummy the JNFnCNTL files. You are placing the entire output data onto the spool. You have F1,F2 as a comment on the JOIN. You don't need to have the negatives of the tests. You can use SAVE for the BOT file. Your OPTION COPY is logically misplaced. And you got two upvotes? If it was from friends, it is kind of them, but you run the risk of sanctions against all three of you, I think. Best if they just remove the votes. Tidy up the answer anyway. It'll then be better than Raja's which has managed two upvotes in two years.

Comment: I have placed the entire data onto spool here as i have given only 2-2 lines of input and as Sekhar asked above "why FILL is used", I thought of showing the entire join output in spool(SORTOUT), its just for explanatory purpose. JNFnCNTL: again here also I just wanted show that this is also an available DD statement which can be used for pre processing of input files before going as input to SORT. could you please help me understand how the OPTION COPY is misplaced

Comment: The question is for SyncSort. Only up-to-date SyncSort has support for JNFnCNTL. There is a patch available for not-quite-up-to-date SyncSort, but nothing available before that.

Comment: Raja dealt with the comment. Perhaps you don't know, but it is permissible to edit the answer to include such information. You get two bonus points if the suggested edit is accepted.

Comment: The OPTION COPY is *logically misplaced*. The way the OPTION card is expected to be used is as the first Control Card. Since, in this case, a JOINKEYS, the OPTION COPY applies to the Main Task only, it is common to see OPTION COPY (or SORT FIELDS=COPY, which is the same thing) as the first card of the Main Task. It does not actually matter (with DFSORT anyway, I don't know for certain for SyncSort) *where* you *code* the OPTION - the actions from the OPTION will always be activated at the first logical point in processing. But if you tuck it at the bottom, next person along may miss it.

Comment: The question remains, with a working but not exceptional solution, how did you come by two upvotes in only a few hours? Anyone upvoting yours should have upvoted Raja's as well, as they are broadly equivalent (although Raja's has errors). Don't try to fix Raja's errors. I've tried. You'll get the suggested edit rejected.

Comment: OUTFIL FNAMES=FILE1,INCLUDE=(17,01,CH,EQ,C'@'),BUILD=(1,16)

Comment: OUTFIL FNAMES=FILE2,INCLUDE=(01,01,CH,EQ,C'@'),BUILD=(17,16)

Comment: OUTFIL FNAMES=BOTH,SAVE,BUILD=(1,16)

Comment: JOIN UNPAIRED or JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2