# JCL for sorting two files and getting the unique records in File2

Tags: sorting, jcl

I would like to sort two files and get the non matching records into output.
File1:
0001000111
0002000211
0002000212
0003000311

File2:

0001000111
0002000210
0002000211
0002000212
0003000311
0004000411

Expected output:

0002000210
0004000411

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Matching and Non-matching records from two input files in one step using SYNCSORT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656172/how-to-get-the-matching-and-non-matching-records-from-two-input-files-in-one-ste)

Comment: Which sort product are you using? (Add that tag) What sort control statements have you used? What are the rules for getting from your input to your output? Please, remove the JCL tag as this is not a JCL question as sort control statement are not JCL. (If you do not believe that last statement then look up your sort control statements in the JCL Language Reference manual)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Joinkeys, that is a tool for to make joins at a JCL.